# Is there an updated guide to the eu_ldap extension for the typo 3?

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, openldap, intraweb

I am trying to simulate an intranet CMS and installed the eu_ldap extension for typo3. Unfortunately the downloaded guide is out of date, and the current manual is of very little use to a typo 3 beginner.
Is it possible to create nodes from within the extension or it has to be defined in the ldap server? Or can users can be created within typo3 then be authenticated via ldap or whether it has to be done on the OS. I'd like to build an intranet system and create users who can create resources using other extensions but I would like to structure access control also. In short I don't understand which functionalities are delegated to the extension and which have to be structured on the server side.
At the moment my best guess as to how to create the domains is to create a domain object with each page that acts as a domain root which will correspond to a node within the ldap (e.g. ou=Members) then create an ldap server object in typo 3 on that page, assuming this works (if it is the way to go about it) how can users be created and given acls? then added to this domain for instance?

Comment: tag intraweb should be intranet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension just provides the authentication service. So can connect the TYPO3 to your ldap by providing the connection data in the extension and then every login attempt is not checked on the TYPO3 side, but redirected to the ldap system. This just sends back whether the user is allowed to login and may provide some more information about the user and the assigned groups.

The ldap system does not know anything about the structure inside your TYPO3, but you can use the groups for access restrictions.

Most of the ldap extensions work like that and depending on whether you want to provide login to frontend, backend or both, there may also be better extensions for your case. You have to be a little more specific on

> I'd like to build an intranet system and create users who can create resources using other extensions but I would like to structure access control also.

What kind of resources do you want them to create? Does that mean frontend or backend? What exactly do you want to have an access control for? Pages or content or plugins/extensions or backend modules?

Comment: I re-edited the question so as not to be as cryptive as the TSRef and documents